# Extracting links from html from the link of the following website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the link

```
/stocks/company_info/stock_news.php?sc_id=CHC&scat=&pageno=2&next=0&durationType=Y&Year=2018&duration=1&news_type=
```

from the html of the page

```
http://www.moneycontrol.com/company-article/piramalenterprises/news/PH05#PH05
```

The following is the code that is used

```
url_list = "http://www.moneycontrol.com/company-article/piramalenterprises/news/PH05#PH05"
html = requests.get(url_list)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text,'html.parser')
link = soup.find_all('a')
print(link)
```

using beautiful soup. How would I go about it, using find_all('a") doesn't return the required link in the returned html.

Comment: Share your code please..

Comment: @balderman it`s the edited version, will it suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this to get Exact Url you want.

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests
import re


sauce = requests.get('https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/company_info/stock_news.php?sc_id=CHC&durationType=Y&Year=2018')

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce.text, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile("company_info")):
   # print(a['href'])
    if 'pageno' in a['href']:
        print(a['href'])
```

output:

```
/stocks/company_info/stock_news.php?sc_id=CHC&scat=&pageno=2&next=0&durationType=Y&Year=2018&duration=1&news_type=
/stocks/company_info/stock_news.php?sc_id=CHC&scat=&pageno=3&next=0&durationType=Y&Year=2018&duration=1&news_type=
```

Comment: it return all the above urls also i only want the specified url, when I try to do     ```blink = a['href']
    #print(blink)
    for b in blink:
        if b.__contains__('pageno') == True:
            print(b)```   I get nothing, how would I go about extracting only the URL I want?

Comment: thanks, I also got it by doing something similar. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use the `get` method to find the `href` attribute:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests

url_list = "http://www.moneycontrol.com/company-article/piramalenterprises/news/PH05#PH05"
html = requests.get(url_list)
page= soup(html.text,'html.parser')
link = page.find_all('a')
for l in link:
    print(l.get('href'))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out again!! Just thinking, is it wise to use a for loop then use __contains__(pageno=2) will be good or is there a better way to find the exact URL I want?

Comment: You have many ways to find a matching value in a list, loop with contains, regex... I don't know what's the best without looking for, but I think you can do a regex with `re` package from json directly in the `find_all` method